# how to retrieve the value of a key in session storage

Tags: vue.js, session-variables

How to retrieve the value of a key in session storage? I want to test the value of a key in session storage in a condition but it returns a negative result yet the value "student " is the value of the "roles" key, here is a schema on the code.

```js
this.$q.sessionStorage.set('current_user', infos)
this.$q.sessionStorage.set('fullname', fullname)
this.$q.sessionStorage.set('roles', roles)

const professorRole = sessionStorage.getItem("roles")
const studentRole = sessionStorage.getItem("roles")

//console.log("stu " + professorRole);

if (studentRole !== null && studentRole.indexOf(2) === "student") {
    
    console.log('email exists');
} else  {
    console.log('email not ok');
}
```

Comment: `this.$q.sessionStorage` and `sessionStorage` don't look like the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either of the methods

`getKey (index) => String,null` or  `getAllKeys () => Array`

on `this.$q.sessionStorage`

to retrieve the value of a key in session storage

Example:

> ```
> let keys = this.$q.sessionStorage.getAllKeys()
> ```